# Clone shadow in native Drag&Drop in HTML5

Tags: javascript, css, html

Hello I have problems with native Drag&Drop in HTML5.

In my site I open something like window popup, I wanna allow the user change the position of that window. So far I used my own code, works perfect, but it's time rewrite it to native HTML5.

Here you can find code with I used now: http://jsfiddle.net/aapbf/6/

```
var box = document.getElementById('box');
function startDrag(e){
    this.mouse = {x: e.clientX,y: e.clientY};
    this.actual = {x: this.style.left, y: this.style.top};
}

function nowDrag(e){
   this.style.left = this.actual.x+e.clientX-this.actual.x+'px';
   this.style.top = this.actual.y+e.clientY-this.actual.y+'px';
   this.textContent = e.clientX; 
}
function handleDrop(){
    this.style.left = this.actual.x+e.clientX-this.actual.x+'px';
    this.style.top = this.actual.y+e.clientY-this.actual.y+'px';
}
box.addEventListener('drag',nowDrag,false);
box.addEventListener('dragstart',startDrag,false);
box.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop, false);
```

The idea how to make is good (change css property) ? How to avoid create this shadow clone of dragging object ? Or how to make shadow clone object to be identical clone of object, so I don’t need to change css property to create moving effect, it's even possible ? It's will be the better option (from optimization view) because the shadow already tracking cursor, what I need.
If you dragged it first time everything is okey, but in the second try nothing happen I can't figure out why.

EDIT:

Maybe I wrote unintelligible. I wanna effect like on this site:

https://web.archive.org/web/20151230131916/https://developer.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/demos/D/a/Darbicus/067780cbcb0cfea29e59def1e1acbc3c/jigsaw-puzzle_1376833848_demo_package/index.html

I predict you write that check source code, I did it.
And what I found ? Something that I hate in internet. Even if I found this example in DRAG&DROP section there nothing about it, they use their own code.  What this example doing there, I don't know.
To sum up: the main problem is shadow clone dragged object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can explicitly set the drag (or "ghost") image inside your `dragstart` handler:

```
function startDrag(e){
    this.mouse = {x: e.clientX,y: e.clientY};
    this.actual = {x: this.style.left, y: this.style.top};
    e.dataTransfer.setDragImage(this, 0, 0); // set the drag image to be the element itself
}
```

Here's some [documentation on the `DataTransfer` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer).

Comment: You have right. How could I miss this function. But of course it isn't that simple, works everywhere except Opera and IE. I go kill myself.  The god's sake, how we can use new feature HTML5 even if the work differently in each browser after 2 years of beggining.

Comment: yes indeed. They support  Drag&Drop but not setDragImage().( I checked on OPERA 12.16). And so, no matter because I don't like FF effect, which with linear gradient fade out big dragged object. I need to stay in my own implementation.